# how to reduce the size of node module?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I have created a private NPM package in gitlab registry after installing my private package node module size become 3 times larger than before just beacause of one package how to reduce the size of node module?

is it because of dev dependency in npm package.json?

Comment: You can also consider using yarn 2 for PnP (Plug n Play) or use pnpm, to completely do away with node_modules

Comment: Switch to deno and remove your node_modules completely.